# Installing an OWIN service in Windows not working

Tags: c#, routes, owin

I'm quite new to OWIN as a technology.  I have a service, and my routing looks something like this:

```
[Route("myMessage/{message}")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[HttpPost]
public void myMessage(string message)
```

I have installed the service like this:

```
installutil My.Service.exe
```

And checked that the service is running under Windows (8).

However, when I try navigating to this URI `http://localhost:1010/myMessage/test`

I get a 404 error.  Is there a way to debug or view whether this is correctly running (for example, in IIS I could select browse)?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your route cannot be resolved.

It seems to me that you're trying to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Make sure you have `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` configured in your `Startup` class:

```
class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    } 
}
```

As you can see I've disabled the standard routing system (`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute`) as I much prefer to define my own routes.

Now your api controller must have an attribute where you configure the prefix for your route with `RoutePrefix`.

Normally you would use some `api/controller` naming:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/messages")]
```

Your controller should look something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/messages")]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [Route("myMessage/{message}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string myMessage(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Your controller's name could even be something totally different:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{

}
```

cause what it matters now is the `RoutePrefix`.

Your controller now should be able to accept request to:

```
localhost:<port>/api/messages/myMessage/<yourmessage>
```

Don't forget to define the right port in your `ServiceBase`:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    myServer = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: "http://localhost:1010/");
}
```